# Find the bounds of a random variable $A$ from $X(t) = acos(At + V)$ where $V \sim Uniform[0, 2\pi]$

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, random-variables

I have this problem where we are supposed to find the mean and covariance of a random process $X(t)$ and in that problem it says that we can assume that $$0 \leq A \leq 2\pi$$ why?

However, I have been struggling a little bit of why.
I tried integrating the double integral as it should sum to 1 but I get 0 (wolfram alpha weirdly also says zero).

I tried isolating $V$ and using its bounds and I get between $0$ and $2$.
At this point I am fairly confused, I would appreciate any pointers and help!

edit:
I think I got it.

$$P(X(t) \leq x) = P(acos(At + V) \leq x) = P(V \leq arccos(\frac{x}{a}) - At$$

Which after some algebra, using that the probability has to be in $[0 ,1] $ yields that
$$0 \leq arccos(\frac{x}{a}) - At \leq 2\pi$$.
qed? Because the domain of the inverse cosine is $ \in [0, 2\pi]$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\cos x$ is a periodic function, and you can write a general A as

$$A = 2 k \pi+ A_{[0,2 \pi]}$$

Where $A_{[0,2 \pi]} = A \mod 2\pi$ and $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Hi Gennaro, thanks a lot, I had tried using that too but hit a the 0 issue after. I think I got it now, would you check my edit? Its much appreciated!